# IE9-32 bit compatability with SP2010

Tags: 2010, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility

I am testing IE9-32 bit compatibility with SP2010.

I have prepared the testcase/usecase for testing our custom SP solutions.

At the same time,i want to test the OOB functionalities of SP2010 with IE9.

Are there any testcases available which i can use for testing the OOB functionailites of SP2010 with IE9?

Answer (score 1):

The below article helped me with my testing:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx